# Apply xslt template on many lines

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML which can have many PurchaseOrderLine sections, distinguished by LineNumber (10, 20, 30 etc). In each one, I need to insert a sub-section inside the UserArea section with the last character of the TaxID. My current xslt works partially, because it always takes the last char from the first line, and puts it on all lines. I can't get it to look at each line individually.

thanks.

Incoming XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncPurchaseOrder xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns:inforpo="http://schema.infor.com/eam/inforbodmodel/100/purchaseorder" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" languageCode="en-US" releaseID="9.2" systemEnvironmentCode="Production" versionID="2.9.1">
    <DataArea>
        <PurchaseOrder>
            <PurchaseOrderLine>
                <LineNumber>10</LineNumber>
                <BuyerParty>
                    <PartyIDs>
                        <TaxID>BFPAA000</TaxID>
                    </PartyIDs>
                </BuyerParty>
                <UserArea>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue name="eam.CostCode">a1</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                </UserArea>
            </PurchaseOrderLine>
            <PurchaseOrderLine>
                <LineNumber>20</LineNumber>
                <BuyerParty>
                    <PartyIDs>
                        <TaxID>BFPAA000XCCN</TaxID>
                    </PartyIDs>
                </BuyerParty>
                <UserArea>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue name="eam.CostCode">a1</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                </UserArea>
            </PurchaseOrderLine>
        </PurchaseOrder>
    </DataArea>
</SyncPurchaseOrder>
```

Current XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" exclude-result-prefixes="my java">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />    

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//my:PurchaseOrder/my:PurchaseOrderLine/my:UserArea/my:Property[my:NameValue/@name='eam.CostCode']">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/> 
    <Property>
        <NameValue name="llp.lastCharTaxCode">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(//my:PurchaseOrder/my:PurchaseOrderLine/my:BuyerParty/my:PartyIDs/my:TaxID, string-length(//my:PurchaseOrder/my:PurchaseOrderLine/my:BuyerParty/my:PartyIDs/my:TaxID), 1)" />
        </NameValue>
    </Property>
   </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncPurchaseOrder xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"
                   xmlns:inforpo="http://schema.infor.com/eam/inforbodmodel/100/purchaseorder"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   languageCode="en-US"
                   releaseID="9.2"
                   systemEnvironmentCode="Production"
                   versionID="2.9.1">
    <DataArea>
        <PurchaseOrder>
            <PurchaseOrderLine>
                <LineNumber>10</LineNumber>
                <BuyerParty>
                    <PartyIDs>
                        <TaxID>BFPAA000</TaxID>
                    </PartyIDs>
                </BuyerParty>
                <UserArea>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue name="eam.CostCode">a1</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue name="llp.lastCharTaxCode">0</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                </UserArea>
            </PurchaseOrderLine>
            <PurchaseOrderLine>
                <LineNumber>20</LineNumber>
                <BuyerParty>
                    <PartyIDs>
                        <TaxID>BFPAA000XCCN</TaxID>
                    </PartyIDs>
                </BuyerParty>
                <UserArea>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue name="eam.CostCode">a1</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue name="llp.lastCharTaxCode">N</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                </UserArea>
            </PurchaseOrderLine>
        </PurchaseOrder>
    </DataArea>
</SyncPurchaseOrder>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of matching the template with `<Property>`, you can match it with `<UserArea>` as below.

```
<xsl:template match="my:UserArea">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="my:Property" />
        <xsl:variable name="taxID" select="../my:BuyerParty/my:PartyIDs/my:TaxID" />
        <Property>
            <NameValue name="llp.lastCharTaxCode">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($taxID, string-length($taxID), 1)" />
            </NameValue>
        </Property>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This will provide the desired output

```
<SyncPurchaseOrder xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"
    xmlns:inforpo="http://schema.infor.com/eam/inforbodmodel/100/purchaseorder"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" languageCode="en-US"
    releaseID="9.2" systemEnvironmentCode="Production" versionID="2.9.1">
    <DataArea>
        <PurchaseOrder>
            <PurchaseOrderLine>
                <LineNumber>10</LineNumber>
                <BuyerParty>
                    <PartyIDs>
                        <TaxID>BFPAA000</TaxID>
                    </PartyIDs>
                </BuyerParty>
                <UserArea>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue name="eam.CostCode">a1</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue name="llp.lastCharTaxCode">0</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                </UserArea>
            </PurchaseOrderLine>
            <PurchaseOrderLine>
                <LineNumber>20</LineNumber>
                <BuyerParty>
                    <PartyIDs>
                        <TaxID>BFPAA000XCCN</TaxID>
                    </PartyIDs>
                </BuyerParty>
                <UserArea>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue name="eam.CostCode">a1</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue name="llp.lastCharTaxCode">N</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                </UserArea>
            </PurchaseOrderLine>
        </PurchaseOrder>
    </DataArea>
</SyncPurchaseOrder>
```